# Can Groupon be trained to know what I like?

Tags: groupon

I like how sites like Amazon and Netflix use recommendation algorithms to figure out what kinds of other products I might be interested in.  Does [Groupon](http://www.groupon.com/) need to be trained to know what I like, or does everyone just see the same deal each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get personalised deals along with the city-wide "spotlight" deal (providing it is a different deal). You need to ensure that you have completed your personalisation information.

[Taken from this GroupOn Blog Post](http://www.groupon.com/blog/cities/personalized-deals-faq/)

> **What do I see if Groupon doesn’t have any personalization information
>   about me?**
>
> There will continue to be a city-wide
>   “spotlight” deal for when we know
>   nothing about a subscriber. If we know
>   a little personalization information,
>   subscribers will see their
>   personalized deal instead (we’ll also
>   show them the city-wide spotlight deal
>   if it’s different).

I don't think their "personalised deals" are as sophisticated as Amazons recommendations etc but it's a start.